# Syntax of ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) is not clear

Tags: objective-c

I don't fully understand the following code. Isn't NSCommandKeyMask a fixed integer ?

Then isn't the second part of the condition always true ?
For instance, isn't the same to: `([theEvent modifiedFlags] & 1)`

```
if ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) {
    NSLog(@"Alt key Down (again)!");
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It absolutely is--but I think you're confusing the boolean and operator with the bitwise and operator. Here, they're performing a bitwise operation on `modifierFlags`. Read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Basically, it performs a calculation on each individual binary digit. In the case of `&`, it results in `1` if both digits are `1`, and `0` otherwise. Example:

```
    0101 (decimal 5)
AND 0011 (decimal 3)
  = 0001 (decimal 1)
```

`modifierFlags` sets each binary place based on some modifier flag, then each mask contains a single one in its appropriate place. Thus, performing this operation results in 0 if that flag is not set, and some non-zero value if that flag *is* set. That's why that if statement works.

Comment: I see. So what if I should check for example if both CMD and SHIFT are pressed at the same time ?

Comment: You'd need to check `([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSCommandKeyMask) && ([theEvent modifierFlags] & NSShiftKeyMask)`.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is not a logical and, but a bitwise and, it checks that the same bit is on in `[theEvent modifierFlags]` as well.

```
1 & 1 == 1 (true)
3 & 1 == 1 (true)
2 & 1 == 0 (false)
```

Also, although `NSCommandKeyMask` is a constant, its value may change one day (in a different version) so you shouldn't use `1` anyway.